# Is it possible to create database by using stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to create database by using stored procedures?

Comment: please don't...

Comment: It is possible. But whats the point in creating a DB via SP?

Comment: @manoj kumar What is in your mind body? Everything are possible

Comment: @manoj kumar , can you please tell us which DB you are working?  mysql or sql-server?

Comment: You could try it and find out (and you would find that the answer is yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create procedure proc_drop_create_db()
Begin

Drop database if Exists thisIsMyDbName;
create database if not exists thisIsYourNewDbName;

end;
```

then `call proc_drop_create_db();`

Comment: But all of this can be happen if you have a right to that database.(Permission)

Comment: Which DB would you store this SP in?

Comment: Great question, thanks @ P. Salmon. Im just giving an option but iv'e never tried this sorry

Comment: Don't have a time to test it.. for now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. In MySQL 8.0.31

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spCreateDataBase`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `spCreateDataBase`(NAME VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN

    SET @DB_CHARSET := ' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4';
    SET @DB_COLLATE := ' DEFAULT COLLATE UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI';

    SET @DROP_DB := CONCAT('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ', NAME);
    SET @CREATE_DB := CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ', NAME, @DB_CHARSET, @DB_COLLATE);

    PREPARE DROP_STMT FROM @DROP_DB; EXECUTE DROP_STMT; DEALLOCATE PREPARE DROP_STMT;
    PREPARE CREATE_STMT FROM @CREATE_DB; EXECUTE CREATE_STMT; DEALLOCATE PREPARE CREATE_STMT;
    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```